# How to distinguish sessions when there is node server between java web server (jetty) and client

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, session, servlets

Node server is applied by our front-end to deal with request from user's browser, and then get data from API served by jetty. It has been validated that all works well when client call API directly. However, we need node server to precess some front end logic. But APIs depended on session will failed when all requests are from node server.

To be clear, the request tracing would be:

> client(browser) <==> node server <==>  API (jetty web server)

For example, one of our APIs captcha service (based on Kaptcha) needs to set generated image into HttpSession in HttpServletRequest. and all requests would be considered from the same point with the same sessionId caused by the forwarding of node server.

The business logic is, when captcha is required, javascript in browser will call node server and then call API server to get captcha. 
Jetty would think all requests from the same client(node server) and the sessionId will be always same, service would keep the last captcha associated with sessionId, however the original requests are from different users. When more than one users access our website, some of them will fail.

Thanks a lot for your time reading this, so is there any way to distinguish the different source from my API without removing the node server?

Thanks again.

Comment: How does the client identify the user? There must be some unique identifier (like a user name or email address) that the client sends, either in the HTTP header or in the body of the request. Can you show the code in the node server that handles the request and forwards it to the jetty API?

Comment: It has been signed in when user request the captcha. I'm not the coder of node but the API. So I don't have the code about node. I have known that the http header is copied and forward to my web server. I can see the cookie is different, but the sessionId generated is still the same.